# How to Reset/Change Administrator ID/Password of Fuji Xerox DocuPrint CM305 df Printer

Tags: password

I forget the administrator ID and password of Fuji Xerox DocuPrint CM305 df printer. How to reset and then change them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice, CM305 has two NVM initialization items. The one under System/Admin Menu/Maintenance menu **doesn't** reset the admin password! Instead, you must run the one under System/Admin Menu/Wired Network menu for resetting. The step to reset the admin password:

1. Go to the front of your CM305 printer.
2. Press **System** button on the printer.
3. Go to **Admin Menu/Wired Network/Initialize NVM** menu.
4. Select Yes and the printer restarts.
5. Go to **Admin Menu/Wired Network/Ethernet** to set your IP.
6. In your PC, open the URL http://YourPrinterIp/ by web browser.
7. Go to **Properties/Security/Administrator** Settings for changing your admin ID and password.
8. Change **Administrator Login ID**.
9. Change **Administrator Password**. Pay attention! The password length is **10** characters. More characters will be trimmed!
10. Press Apply button. It will ask you the old admin ID and password. Because we have reset the admin ID and password, we enter the default admin ID and password for CM305: **11111** and **x-admin**
11. Done!

Comment: works for DocuPrint C1100. You be blessed for this.

Answer (score 0):

Above instructions also reset the web user interface password to default on **Fuji Xerox DocuPrint C3210 DX**.

Also known as Fuji Film DocuPrint C3210 DX

follow the instructions and login after reboot with

11111
x-admin